# How to read from MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb, bson

I am trying to read a row from my MongoDB with the following code

```
public static void MongoConnection()
{
    var connectionString = "127.0.0.1";

    var mongoClient = new MongoClient(connectionString);

    var mongoServer = mongoClient.GetServer();

    var databaseName = "PointToPoint";
    var db = mongoServer.GetDatabase(databaseName);
    var mongodb = db.GetCollection("OCS.MeterEntity");

    BsonDocument documentRead = mongodb.FindOne(new QueryDocument {
    {"_id", "4B414D000000011613CD" }
});
```

But the documentRead is always null and i know the specifik _id exists in the database. What am i doing wrong?

It does connect to the database and the right table.

Comment: Localhost? 127.0.0.1 last time I checked.

Comment: read this article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/321741/MongoDB-with-C-NET

Comment: you are right i made a typo, I just wrote a random nr there because I did not want you to know where I am trying to connect :)

Comment: What data type is the `_id` stored as in the document? If it's really an `ObjectId`, you'll need to pass one: `ObjectId.Parse("id here")`

Comment: it is stored as a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mannaged to figure it out :)

```
public static void MongoConnection()
        {
            var connectionString = "mongodb://localhost";
            var mongoClient = new MongoClient(connectionString);
            var mongoServer = mongoClient.GetServer();
            var databaseName = "PointToPoint";
            var db = mongoServer.GetDatabase(databaseName);
            var mongodb = db.GetCollection<MongoDBModel>("OCS.MeterEntity");
            var mongodbQuery = Query<MongoDBModel>.EQ(x => x._id, "4B414D000000011613CD");
            var foundMongoDB = mongodb.FindOne(mongodbQuery);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a calling convention:

```
new QueryDocument( "_id", new ObjectId("4B414D000000011613CD") )
```

but this should work as well:

```
new BSONDocument { { "_id", "4B414D000000011613CD" } }
```