# monogodb update specific field only in c#

Tags: c#, mongodb

```
"_id" : ObjectId("60b51564d6f7ba2ddf61217b"), 
"fr-FR" : {
    "Options" : "Ops", 
    "Dashboard saved successfully" : "Dashboard Saved"
}, 
"Default" : true
```

// ----------------------------------------------

```
"_id" : ObjectId("60b51571d6f7ba2ddf61217c"), 
"en-EU" : {
    "Options" : "Choice", 
    "Dashboard saved successfully" : "Dashboard created successfully"
}, 
"Default" : false
```

// ----------------------------------------------

```
"_id" : ObjectId("60b5157ed6f7ba2ddf61217d"), 
"en-EN" : {
    "Dashboard saved successfully" : "Dashboard created successfully", 
    "Options" : "Choice1"
}, 
"Default" : false
```

I have these 3 documents in MongoDB.
I want to update "en-EU.Options" value only.
I don't get id while updating.
I just have lang. the name means "en-EU" and key "Options".
please help me.

```
string update = "en-EU.Options";
string value = "abcd";
var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Update.Set(update, value);
collection = mongoDB.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("lang");
collection.UpdateOne(BsonDocumentFilterDefinition<BsonDocument>.Empty, filter, new UpdateOptions { IsUpsert = false });
```

Comment: You should show some (C#) code, which you tried to solve this problem. Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22348282/how-to-read-from-mongodb) can help ?

Comment: You may use a repository. This will cover many things: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Repository.Mongo Check these sample codes: https://github.com/esendir/MongoRepository

Comment: @fatihyildizhan check this out: https://mongodb-entities.com

Answer (score 0):

you need the $exists operator

```cs
var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Exists("en-US.Options");
var update = Builders<BsonDocument>.Update.Set("en-EU.Options", "abcd");
await collection.UpdateOneAsync(filter, update);
```